# cloning SSD onto bigger SSD and resize - alignment or other low level stuff?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, gparted

I have a Dell M4700, one 128GB mSata SSD, one HDD, 16 GB RAM, some i7 CPU. Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64, installed on SSD, HDD for storage and some big programs.

The Windows works fine, all programs work fine, no need for reinstall.

Very soon I will change the 128 GB mSata SSD to a 256 GB.

Question: I would boot into gparted (or another debian) on USB stick and do a dd to clone the 128GB SSD into the 256GB SSD. Then I would do a resize using gparted.

Question: Can I do this or should I install the OS from scratch because of alignment of the sectors or some other low level stuff going on?

Is gparted doing this not-visible-to-the-user-low-level-stuff correctely?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem with just cloning the smaller partition on the larger drive and then enlarging it.